# Like vue js, I want to display the screens for administrators and users with react js as one js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

Like vue js, I want to display the screens for administrators and users with react js as one js.

Hello I am not good at English. Thank you for your understanding

for vue js

Into one js file

Each template html can be divided into an administrator screen and a user screen.

Is it possible for react js as well?

if not

if(is_admin) {
Components for administrators
} else {
Components for users
}

Should we develop like this?

Please advice

Thank you.

Comment: { (is_admin) ? <Admin /> : <User /> }

Comment: This is the role that a router usually takes. *Like vue js,* - Vue doesn't have special treatment for this. if you did this in Vue, extrapolate your knowledge to React.